# High availability MySQL with HA Proxy failover

Tags: mysql, haproxy, high-availability

I am looking to load balance a Percona cluster behind two HA Proxy nodes with failover (using keepalived) so there is no single point of failure. I have HA Proxy already setup with keepalived using a virtual IP. My questions/confusion is regarding how my app server clients should now connect to HA proxy to have the result routed to one of the Percona nodes.

The virtual IP created by keepalived is only accessible/pingable from the two HA proxy servers, not from any client node, so how do I connect a client to the HA proxies without using their individual IP's (to ensure failover works)? Do I need to installed keepalived on every client server as well?

Comment: Something about "The virtual IP created by keepalived is only accessible/pingable from the two HA proxy servers" doesn't seem right, did you create the virtual IP in another network?

Comment: Yep, I did, is that the problem? The local network IP's are 10.x.x.x and I created a virtual IP for 192.168.1.100 (I thought this would prevent possible IP conflicts). Is that my mistake?

If so, does this mean it's not possible to achieve failover from an outside network?

Comment: Not at all, although you should create the virtual IP in a network you can route to. You can create the virtual IP in the same local network, or a different one, but your clients will have to know how to reach the network that your virtual IP is in. If the network is a "private one" your NAT router will need to know how to get it there, if the clients are also in private networks, just their gateway will have to route the traffic appropriately.

Comment: Apologies if I sound dense, but if I want clients on the same network (10.x.x.x) to access the virtual IP, do I simply need to make my virtual IP on the 10.x.x.x network instead of 192.x.x.x and the IP will be accessible?

Comment: You don't sound dense, don't worry. Making the virtual IP in the 10.x.x.x network would be the simplest way of ensuring that they can connect to the virtual IP, as it will not require changing anything else.